# Possible to enabled quoted fields globally in FileHelpers engine?

Tags: filehelpers

I know one can use the FieldQuoted attribute on a field by field basis.  I have a large number of fields/columns.  Possible to  have the entire class get this option/attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no class-wide setting for `FieldQuoted` in FileHelpers. You do need to apply it to each field.